# How to get content to slide up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of menus that when clicked will slide down to reveal some content. 
My problem is, is that I would like the option on top to slide up instead of down.

My code for the menu

```
<div class="additional-navigation-wrapper">
    <div class="additional-navigation">
        <a class="border-bottom-white padding-level-one inactive additional-nav-info1" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <h4>info</h4>
            <img class="nav-arrow no-action floatright" src="images/nav-arrow-white.png" />
            <span class="clearboth"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="additional-nav-info-wrapper1">
            <div class="additional-nav-info-inner1" style="display: none;">
                <ul>
                    <h3>Some information</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tristique nisi et diam sagittis, scelerisque lacinia justo dictum. Maecenas neque     dolor, sodales vel dolor eget, scelerisque molestie tellus. Aenean ut tristique quam. Nullam id convallis augue. Duis ut sem sed lorem tempor     fermentum eget mattis ligula. Mauris cursus, dolor quis pellentesque porta, lacus ipsum ornare metus, nec volutpat arcu justo id turpis. Nunc     tempus libero non lacus sagittis, nec condimentum nulla fringilla. Duis id ultrices velit. Nunc at sem quis mauris commodo tempor. Phasellus     sit amet est rhoncus ipsum egestas varius quis et quam. Nulla in risus sit amet quam vulputate dapibus et non elit. Cras facilisis congue odio,     sit amet posuere metus eleifend sed. 
                    </p>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="additional-navigation-wrapper">
        <div class="additional-navigation">
            <a class="border-bottom-white padding-level-one inactive additional-nav-info2" href="javascript:void(0);">Lorem ipsum
<img class="nav-arrow no-action floatright" src="images/nav-arrow-white.png" />
                <span class="clearboth"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="additional-nav-info-wrapper2">
                <div class="additional-nav-info-inner2" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        Praesent tempor eleifend nibh, nec rutrum est tristique at. Nulla fermentum posuere posuere. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus dapibus tristique    urna, quis eleifend quam dapibus vel. Sed tempor ipsum ipsum, a tristique est tincidunt ac. Curabitur eu erat semper purus lacinia dignissim.    Proin pretium hendrerit nisl, vitae ultricies erat adipiscing vitae. Aliquam scelerisque nisl sit amet molestie euismod. 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="additional-navigation">
            <a class="border-bottom-white padding-level-one inactive additional-nav-info3" href="javascript:void(0);">Lorem ipsum
<img class="nav-arrow no-action inactive floatright" src="images/nav-arrow-white.png" />
                <span class="clearboth"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="additional-nav-info-wrapper3">
                <div class="additional-nav-info-inner3" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        Suspendisse potenti. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur volutpat quam ac pretium varius. Vivamus et commodo sapien. Praesent eu pulvinar neque. Etiam      faucibus sapien sit amet odio adipiscing vestibulum. Aliquam in elit quis augue iaculis dictum id vel lacus. Curabitur vel ligula eget enim    imperdiet dapibus id non lacus. Phasellus nec massa quis neque fermentum convallis ac at dolor. Nulla lacus velit, feugiat ut scelerisque sit    amet, semper sit amet nibh. Ut auctor justo ligula, ac aliquam massa dictum a. Phasellus sed sapien tincidunt, dignissim turpis vitae, pretium    elit. Nulla dictum ac diam id lobortis.
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="additional-navigation">
            <a class="border-bottom-white padding-level-one inactive additional-nav-info4" href="javascript:void(0);">Lorem ipsum
<img class="nav-arrow no-action floatright" src="images/nav-arrow-white.png" />
                <span class="clearboth"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="additional-nav-info-wrapper4">
                <div class="additional-nav-info-inner4" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        Maecenas sollicitudin et velit nec consectetur. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam venenatis elit vel elit     porta, ac pretium arcu commodo. Curabitur nec diam eu eros dignissim vestibulum. Donec tellus justo, aliquet non nunc vel, accumsan gravida     ligula. Mauris eu consequat mi, sed euismod nulla. Vestibulum luctus tempor tortor suscipit ultrices. Vestibulum in justo vel purus tincidunt   convallis. Integer varius facilisis urna in scelerisque. Aliquam mattis neque eget arcu blandit, a mollis ligula consectetur. 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="additional-navigation">
            <a class="border-bottom-white padding-level-one inactive additional-nav-info5" href="javascript:void(0);">Lorem ipsum
<img class="nav-arrow no-action floatright" src="images/nav-arrow-white.png" />
                <span class="clearboth"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="additional-nav-info-wrapper5">
                <div class="additional-nav-info-inner5" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        Aliquam sed tellus eget nunc ultricies pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
                        Sed fermentum, ante fermentum faucibus blandit, risus quam tristique justo, a feugiat odio nisl commodo augue. 
                        Nulla facilisi. 
                        Aenean    hendrerit tortor vulputate cursus laoreet. Morbi libero leo, elementum eu lectus nec, fringilla imperdiet purus. Quisque eget odio tempus,     ultricies orci eu, dictum dolor. Curabitur at lectus ac ipsum lobortis consectetur non a tellus. Donec vestibulum sapien et consequat         venenatis. Sed in velit nulla. Nulla commodo, mi at lacinia blandit, tellus dui vestibulum dolor, ac interdum libero arcu a mi. Duis in neque a nulla varius laoreet. Etiam et purus adipiscing, adipiscing est vitae, porttitor nulla. 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="additional-navigation">
            <a class="border-bottom-white padding-level-one inactive additional-nav-info6" href="javascript:void(0);">Lorem ipsum
<img class="nav-arrow no-action floatright" src="images/nav-arrow-white.png" />
                <span class="clearboth"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="additional-nav-info-wrapper6">
                <div class="additional-nav-info-inner6" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu ultrices turpis, at ornare tellus. Integer at gravida tellus. Fusce at aliquet sem. Suspendisse condimentum laoreet bibendum. Nam id aliquam arcu. Vivamus vulputate purus vitae ipsum elementum, vitae feugiat risus pellentesque. Nam vel turpis dolor. Phasellus turpis lacus, facilisis ac lectus sed, imperdiet tempor sem. Duis sed tortor ac urna ultrices sagittis id vitae dolor. Duis mattis venenatis dui sit amet luctus. Fusce eu felis sed dui blandit volutpat. Nullam pharetra pellentesque quam ut laoreet. 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="additional-navigation">
            <a class="border-bottom-white padding-level-one active contact-details-onpage" href="javascript:void(0);">Lorem ipsum
<img class="nav-arrow no-action floatright" src="images/nav-arrow-blue-one.png" />
                <span class="clearboth"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="contact-details-onpage-wrapper">
                <div class="contact-details-onpage-inner" style="display: block;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">EMAIL US
<img src="images/email-ico.png" />
                                <img style="display: none;" src="images/email-ico-active.png" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">08000 58 24 50
<img src="images/telephone-ico.png" />
                                <img style="display: none;" src="images/telephone-ico-active.png" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">OUR PORTFOLIO
<img src="images/portfolio-ico.png" />
                                <img style="display: none;" src="images/portfolio-ico-active.png" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>

                            <a href="#">CONTACT FORM
<img src="images/contact-form-ico.png" />
                                <img style="display: none;" src="images/contact-form-ico-active.png" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <div class="clearboth"></div>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearboth"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my css

```
html, body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000000;
}

.border-bottom-blue {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #43b6cf;
}

.padding-level-one {
    padding: 0 22px;
}

.additional-navigation-wrapper {
}

.additional-navigation .nav-arrow {
    padding: 0;
}

.additional-navigation-wrapper a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.additional-navigation .active {
    color: #43b6cf;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #43b6cf;
}

.csstransitions .additional-navigation-wrapper a {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.additional-navigation-wrapper a:hover {
    color: #43b6cf;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #43b6cf;
}

.contact-details-onpage-inner {
    padding: 40px 22px 2px;
}

    .contact-details-onpage-inner ul {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .contact-details-onpage-inner li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        height: 23px;
        margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    }

        .contact-details-onpage-inner li img {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .contact-details-onpage-inner li a {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: relative;
            padding: 10px 5px 2px 30px;
        }

            .contact-details-onpage-inner li a:hover {
                border: none;
                color: #ffffff;
            }
```

and here is my jquery

```
$(".additional-nav-info0").click(function () {
    if ($(".additional-nav-info-inner0").css("display") == "block") {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner0").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner0").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner0 a").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".additional-nav-info1").click(function () {
    if ($(".additional-nav-info-inner1").css("display") == "block") {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner1").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner1").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner1 a").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".additional-nav-info2").click(function () {
    if ($(".additional-nav-info-inner2").css("display") == "block") {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner2").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner2").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner2 a").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".additional-nav-info3").click(function () {
    if ($(".additional-nav-info-inner3").css("display") == "block") {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner3").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner3").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner3 a").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".additional-nav-info4").click(function () {
    if ($(".additional-nav-info-inner4").css("display") == "block") {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner4").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner4").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner4 a").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".additional-nav-info5").click(function () {
    if ($(".additional-nav-info-inner5").css("display") == "block") {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner5").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner5").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner5 a").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function () {
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".additional-nav-info6").click(function () {
    if ($(".additional-nav-info-inner6").css("display") == "block") {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner6").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner6").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});
```

Here is a link to JSFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/cerberus478/58Jm7/1/

Comment: sorry what do you mean by `the option on top to slide up instead of down`

Comment: The one that says "Info" was the one I meant

Comment: not sure what you wants... but the current script can be simplifies as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qtrpE/1/

Comment: Thanks for helping simplify it. What I want is for the "info" section to slide up instead of sliding down as it does in the jsfiddle. Does that help?

Comment: you want the `h4` element to slide down

Comment: I want it to slide up

Comment: not sure which element you are talking about... do you want the clicked `additional-nav-infox` element to slide up and the related `additional-nav-info-innerx` element to slide down

Comment: There is a couple of options that can be clicked, they are info and lorem ipsum. I want the content in info to go up while the content in lorem ipsum goes down. Does that make sense?

Comment: the problem is you are talking about the text but I want to know which elements needs to be targeted... so please share the element's class/id attributes

Comment: The element that needs to be targeted is .additional-nav-info-inner1

Answer (score 0):

```
.slideToggle({direction: 'up'}, 250);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".additional-nav-info1").click(function(){
            if($(".additional-nav-info-inner1").css("display") == "block"){
                $(this).removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("inactive");
                $(".additional-nav-info-inner1").stop().slideToggle(250);
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("inactive");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".additional-nav-info-inner1").stop().slideToggle({direction: 'up'}, 250);
            }
        });        
</script>
```

and now, you need add just add position:absolute; to .additional-nav-info1.

Comment: you really need use a slide? you can use an accordion http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: I wouldn't mind using the accordian but I want the one option to go up instead of down. There is a couple of options that can be clicked, they are info and lorem ipsum. I want the content in info to go up while the content in lorem ipsum goes down

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".additional-nav-info1").click(function(){
    if($(".additional-nav-info-inner1").css("display") == "block"){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner1").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner1").stop().slideToggle(250);
        var dHeight = $(".additional-nav-info-inner1 ul").height();
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: '+=' + dHeight + 'px' }, 250);
    }
});
```

**<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58Jm7/2/)</kbd>**